# ETXTBSY error when installing esbuild in Docker container

Tags: node.js, docker, esbuild

I'm encountering an error while trying to install the npm package "esbuild" in a Docker build process. The build was working fine previously, and I haven't made any significant changes recently. However, the build now fails with the following error message:

```
 => ERROR [stage-0 5/6] RUN npm install                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          6.6s
------
 > [stage-0 5/6] RUN npm install:
#0 6.440 npm notice 
#0 6.440 npm notice New minor version of npm available! 9.6.7 -> 9.7.1
#0 6.440 npm notice Changelog: <https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v9.7.1>
#0 6.440 npm notice Run `npm install -g npm@9.7.1` to update!
#0 6.440 npm notice 
#0 6.441 npm ERR! code 1
#0 6.441 npm ERR! path /app/node_modules/esbuild
#0 6.441 npm ERR! command failed
#0 6.441 npm ERR! command sh -c node install.js
#0 6.442 npm ERR! node:internal/errors:496
#0 6.442 npm ERR!     ErrorCaptureStackTrace(err);
#0 6.442 npm ERR!     ^
#0 6.442 npm ERR! 
#0 6.442 npm ERR! <ref *1> Error: spawnSync /app/node_modules/esbuild/bin/esbuild ETXTBSY
#0 6.442 npm ERR!     at Object.spawnSync (node:internal/child_process:1117:20)
#0 6.442 npm ERR!     at spawnSync (node:child_process:871:24)
#0 6.442 npm ERR!     at Object.execFileSync (node:child_process:914:15)
#0 6.442 npm ERR!     at validateBinaryVersion (/app/node_modules/esbuild/install.js:98:28)
#0 6.442 npm ERR!     at /app/node_modules/esbuild/install.js:285:5 {
#0 6.442 npm ERR!   errno: -26,
#0 6.442 npm ERR!   code: 'ETXTBSY',
#0 6.442 npm ERR!   syscall: 'spawnSync /app/node_modules/esbuild/bin/esbuild',
#0 6.442 npm ERR!   path: '/app/node_modules/esbuild/bin/esbuild',
#0 6.442 npm ERR!   spawnargs: [ '--version' ],
#0 6.442 npm ERR!   error: [Circular *1],
#0 6.442 npm ERR!   status: null,
#0 6.442 npm ERR!   signal: null,
#0 6.442 npm ERR!   output: null,
#0 6.442 npm ERR!   pid: 0,
#0 6.442 npm ERR!   stdout: null,
#0 6.443 npm ERR!   stderr: null
#0 6.443 npm ERR! }
#0 6.443 npm ERR! 
#0 6.443 npm ERR! Node.js v20.3.0
#0 6.443 
#0 6.443 npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /root/.npm/_logs/2023-06-13T03_18_04_432Z-debug-0.log
```

I tried clearing the Docker cache and removing any linked node_modules directory but the problem persists. I can reproduce this locally and in CI.

Comment: After regenerating the `package-lock.json` file, npm removed `esbuild` entries  for several other architectures in the lockfile and the problem disappeared. The only remaining entry left is for darwin-arm64 which corresponds to my host computer arch but not the one which Docker would use. I haven't found the root cause for why the additional entries triggered the error so I am leaving the question open for now.

Comment: Same issue here. We are not using Windows or Vagrant. We are building in GCP. Impossible to reproduce this error locally. Impossible to fix it as we actually need esbuild

Answer (score 10):

I was using `node:20.3.0-bullseye-slim` as a base image and fixed the issue by rollbacking to a previous version (`node:20.2.0-bullseye-slim`).

Answer (score 0):

Try to write the version of the image in the dockerfile
It helped me

```
FROM --platform=linux/amd64 node:19.5.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I had encountered the same error

I'm using node:20.3-alpine3.18 but i didn't want to rollback to a different version because it was running on any other machine.

```
16.96 npm ERR! <ref *1> Error: spawnSync /app/node_modules/esbuild/bin/esbuild ETXTBSY
...
npm ERR!   errno: -26,
npm ERR!   code: 'ETXTBSY',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'spawnSync /app/node_modules/esbuild/bin/esbuild',
npm ERR!   path: '/app/node_modules/esbuild/bin/esbuild',
...
```

However, I had some features from Docker Desktop activated, including 'Use Rosetta for x86/amd64 emulation...' on my M1 Mac.

I decided to disable the 'Use Rosetta' option in Docker Desktop.
After disabling 'Use Rosetta for x86/amd64 emulation...', I rebuilt my Docker container, and the build process ran smoothly without any file locking issues. My npm packages were installed correctly, and the project is up and running again. I hope this solution proves beneficial to anyone encountering a similar issue.

[image: Docker Desktop Use Rosetta location]